# Use waitress as a production server for Flask

Tags: python, windows, flask, waitress

I have written an application in Python/Flask which I need to deploy in production on a Windows Server(unfortunately). I came across a suggestion to use Waitress. It was a simple modification to make the web app use waitress, but my issues remain unsolved.

To server using waitress I have modified the code as below(just a basic example)

```
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # app.run()
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

Now I can run this from the command prompt via(same as without waitress)

```
python myapp.py
```

But I cannot use this in production.

- How do I make sure that the server keeps running in case someone closes the cmd prompt.
- How to make sure when the server is rebooted, the webapp comes up automatically without a user having to login and launch the app again.

If these two basic issues are not solvable then I wonder why waitress claims to be a production ready server :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue, reason why i read your question before I add mine.
How is your app.py file named?

Comment: May I ask will this work if you visit a secure domain/hostname rather than an http:// IP address?

Answer (score 1):

Waitress isn't responsible to init your server.
It's just a way to activate WSGI

To init the service after restart just add to windows startup programs.
Validate the server is up there are few ways to do so,the simple running a shell script that check the if the process up and execute it if not

Answer (score -1):

I have just posted a answer to my own similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59893782/how-to-exit-cleanly-from-flask-and-waitress-running-as-a-windows-pywin32-service).
I think you will find that it answers this question too :-)